# Retrieve the count of value from the global variable and select any random from the value

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

I have defined a list variable in the global variable section in Katalon studio, I want to retrieve the count of the list item and select any random value from it .

[image]

I have around 25 values,

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code:

```
def patientName = []
patientName = GlobalVariable.patientList
int length = patientName.size()
    
println "---->"+ length
    
int min = 0;
int max = length-1;
int random_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    
def patientRetrieve = patientName[random_int]
println "---->"+ patientRetrieve
```